# HTML5 Web messaging - does not work locally

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain

I am playing with HTML5 WebMessaging. I just tried with a simple example of sending one message cross-site. It *works* when sending it to public site (see example below - jsbin address of iframe) but it does not work if I use the very same code (as on jsbin) deployed on my local computer (with web page set up at `http://192.168.1.20/web_messaging/b.html`).

I am using timeout for iframe to get ready, origin check is skipped intentionally (for testing).

Any ideas what can be wrong?

code of "client":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://jsbin.com/eKUguFO/1"></iframe> 

<!--<iframe id="iframe" src="http://192.168.1.20/web_messaging/b.html">  doesn't work!-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var win = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow;

window.setTimeout(function() 
{win.postMessage('Hello111', "http://jsbin.com");}, 2000);

//win.postMessage('Hello100', "http://192.168.1.20");

</script>
 <h2>WMTest - A2</h2> 
<div id="output"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real problem was that there no closing iframe tag in your localserver case, as result no javascript executed to send message. Following code works for me localy just with IPs(no domain names).

b.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- <iframe id="iframe" src="http://jsbin.com/eKUguFO/1"></iframe>  -->

<iframe id="iframe" src="http://xx.xx.xx.2/web_messaging/c.html"> </iframe>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var win = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow;

window.setTimeout(function() {
win.postMessage('Hello111!!!', "http://xx.xx.xx.2");
//win.postMessage('Hello100', "http://a.test.com");
}, 2000);

//win.postMessage('Hello100', "http://192.168.1.20");

</script>
 <h2>WMTest - A2</h2> 
<div id="output"></div>
</html>
```

c.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>.postMessage target</title>
<style>
body { 
  font: normal 16px/20px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<strong>This iframe is located on jsbin.com (different domain)</strong>
<p id="test">Send me a message!</p>
<script>
window.onmessage = function(e){
  if ( e.origin !== "http://anydomain.com" ) {
    //return;
  }

  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = e.origin + " said: " + e.data;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did try, with no success. I modified hosts file (verified that domains are reachable at both sides) but it didn't help. Is the example working for you? (You can copy the code jsbin and run load it locally)

Comment: oh, silly me, I didn't notice that! Now it works well, big thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I used firebug to see generated HTML and found out there no code after that IFRAME.